# enum uniform initialization on GCC-4.4.7

Tags: c++, gcc, enums

I am trying to remove `memset` with `uniform initialization` in a legacy code base. Maximum supported GCC version is `4.4.7`. Every thing else seems to work fine but enums.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <utility>                                                                                                                                                    

enum TT{xx,yy,zz};

TT p = {}; 

struct B{};

int main()
{  

    TT x = {}; 
    x = {};
    B r = {}; 
    r = {}; 
}
```

It gives me errors with `gcc4.4.7`:

```
$ /opt/gcc-4.4.7/bin/g++ -Wall question.cpp  -std=c++0x
question.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
question.cpp:15: error: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘TT’
```

And yes, it does compile on gcc4.8.5.

My question is, how can I make it work with my gcc version?

Comment: I think the problem is simply your compiler does not support `uniform initialization`. The concept was introduced way after gcc 4.4.7 came out. So you either need to upgrade your compiler or have to work with "old" c++

Comment: Well it does support `uniform initialization` for structs but fails for enums.

Comment: Uniform initialization is a c++ 11 concept that you can initialize everything the same way. Maybe this syntax for structs was just there before c++11 and they decided to apply this to all the other types. So you can initialize structs with `{}` but it's not **uniform**. Simply put: your compiler is too old.

Comment: Have you tried `x = TT{};` ?

Comment: Yes, I tried `x= TT{}` and `x = decltype(x){}`, both did not work. And `decltype` correctly deduces `x's` type(So, no problems in decltype at least).